# Node.JS/Javascript - casting string to integer is returning NaN when I wouldn't expect it to

Tags: javascript, string, node.js, casting

This is all in the context of a larger program, so Im going to try  keep it simple, showing the offending lines only. I have an array of values that are numbers in string form a la "84", "32", etc.

Yet THIS line

```
console.log(unsolved.length + " " + unsolved[0] + " " + parseInt(unsolved[0]) + " " + parseInt("84"));
```

prints:

```
4 "84" NaN 84
```

"84" is the array element Im trying to parseInt! Yet it won't work unless I take it out of the context of an array and have it explicitly written. What's going on?

Comment: does `unsolved[0]` include the double quotes in its actual value?

Comment: the value of `unsolved[0]` appears to be `'"84"'` instead of `'84'`

Comment: it does - that must be the problem, I think

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try removing the quotations from the string to be processed using this function:

```
function stripAlphaChars(source) { 
  var out = source.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 

  return out; 
}
```

Also you should explicitly specify that you want to parse a base 10 number:

```
parseInt(unsolved[0], 10);
```

Comment: Used this - changed return value to m_strOut though :)

Answer (score 7):

`parseInt` would take everything from the start of its argument that looks like a number, and disregard the rest. In your case, the argument you're calling it with starts with `"`, so nothing looks like a number, and it tries to cast an empty string, which is really not a number.

Answer (score 3):

You should make sure that the array element is indeed a string which is possible to parse to a number. Your array element doesn't contain the value `'84'`, but actually the value `'"84"'` (a string containing a number encapsulated by ")

You'll want to remove the `"` from your array elements, possible like this:

```
function removeQuotationMarks(string) {
  return (typeof string === 'string') ? string.replace(/"|'/g, '') : string;
}

unsolved = unsolved.map(removeQuotationMarks);
```

Now all the array elements should be ready to be parsed with `parseInt(unsolved[x], 10)`

Comment: Great effort :)

Answer (score 0):

First we need to replace " to ' in give data using Regex and replace and then we need to cast.

```js
var i = 1;
var j = "22"
function stringToNumber(n) {
  return (typeof n === 'string') ? parseInt(Number(n.replace(/"|'/g, ''))) : n;
}

console.log(stringToNumber(i)); // 1
console.log(stringToNumber(j)); // 22
```